# Laravel join on returned query with get()

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I'm working with a Laravel 5 project whereby I'm using a trait to create reusable logic and generic functions that are easy to read and consume.

One of these functions, `getDevices` simply returns a collection of all of my devices, however, my function `getCalls` needs to run a join on the returned collection of my `getDevices` and without duplicating my `getDevices` function or moving the model into the `getCall` I'm not sure what I'm missing and how I can achieve such result.

I'm getting an error in my view saying that the join method does not exist.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::join does not exist.

```php
<?php
​
namespace App\Traits;
​
use App\Models\Device;
use App\Models\DeviceGroupsCalls;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;
​
trait Calls {
​
  /*
  * Get all devices
  */
  protected function getDevices()
  {
    return Device::get();
  }
​
​
  /*
  * Get all enabled devices
  */
  protected function getEnabledDevices()
  {
    return Device::where('enabled', true)->get();
  }
​
​
  /*
  * Get all disabled devices
  */
  protected function getDisabledDevices()
  {
    return Device::where('enabled', false)->get();
  }
​
​
  /*
  * get all calls by devices
  */
  protected function getCalls()
  {
    $query = $this->getDevices();
    $devices = $query->join('devicegroupscalls', 'devicegroupscalls.device_groups_id', '=', 'devices.device_groups_id')
                     ->where('devices.enabled', true)
                     ->where('devicegroupscalls.enabled', true)
                     ->first();
​
    return $devices;
  }
​
}
```

Comment: Get is terminating call and will return a collection instead of a query builder, you should do Device::all->join etc.

Also ->first() will only return the first device, if you want to get all the devices you should use ->get();

Comment: `get()` returns the results and is no longer a query builder object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already get result then you are joining record which is not proper. Please see updated file.

```
<?php
​
namespace App\Traits;
​
use App\Models\Device;
use App\Models\DeviceGroupsCalls;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;
​
trait Calls {
​
  /*
  * Get all devices
  */
  protected function getDevices()
  {
    return new Device;
  }
​
​
  /*
  * Get all enabled devices
  */
  protected function getEnabledDevices()
  {
    return Device::where('enabled', true);
  }
​
​
  /*
  * Get all disabled devices
  */
  protected function getDisabledDevices()
  {
    return Device::where('enabled', false);
  }
​
​
  /*
  * get all calls by devices
  */
  protected function getCalls()
  {
    $query = $this->getDevices();
    $devices = $query->join('devicegroupscalls', 'devicegroupscalls.device_groups_id', '=', 'devices.device_groups_id')
                     ->where('devices.enabled', true)
                     ->where('devicegroupscalls.enabled', true)
                     ->first();
​
    return $devices;
  }
​
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says (`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::join does not exist.`) you try to use a Laravel query method on Collection.
You have to use this method (`join`) before you execute methods like `get()`, `first()` (these methods execute query to database).
In method `getDevices()` instead using `get()` try to use `query()`. This will create query builder instance instead of getting data from database (and returns Laravel collection)